# Gitlab API for automating TAG gets an error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I established a CI/CD pipeline with GitLab. I've created a variable to make an automated TAG called ADD_TAG.

I've put the below script

```
REF=$$2
TAG_NAME=$$1
TOKEN=$$ANDROID_CHANGELOG_PRIVATE_TOKEN
URL="$${CI_SERVER_URL}/api/v4/projects/$${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags"
PARAMS="tag_name=$${TAG_NAME}&ref=$${REF}"


curl --fail --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $${TOKEN}" "$${URL}?$${PARAMS}"
```

but I got the below error

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use single `$` when referencing a variables.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#predefined-cicd-variables

For example:

```
URL="$${CI_SERVER_URL}/api/v4/projects/$${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags"
```

should be

```
URL="${CI_SERVER_URL}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags"
```